# LinearLayout too wide / wrong size calculation of images

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-imageview

I have a `LinearLayout` that has only images in it. The image size is reduced as the height of the layout is not sufficiant. Images are sized correctly.
However: The width of the `LinearLayout` is too wide. It is actually the size the images would have if `adjustviewbound=false` would be set instead of `true` as it is in my case.

This appears to be a problem with the `RelativeLayout` around it. If I use a `LinearLayout` for the page, the calculation is correct.

Any ideas how to get the correct width? (no, I can not change the `RelativeLayout`).

Here is the layout for you to try (I used Android 4.3 API 18):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/map_Test"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="10dp"
    android:background="@color/red"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/map_DrillDownImage1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_alert" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/map_DrillDownImage2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```